# Why do we need PodDisruptionBudget on AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am going to implement PDB on AKS. Can someone please tell me why do we need it when we can use node autoscaler.

Also, does PDB allow zero unavailability by creating a node when one of the nodes fails?

Answer (score 3):

[PDB](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) allows you to set rules before evicting your pods from a node.

Let's say you have a 2 nodes cluster and a deployment with 1 replica and you want to update your nodes.

- `kubectl drain` will cordon `node 1` so no pods can be schedule on that node
- `kubectl drain` will remove the pod schedule on `node 1`
- `kubelet` will then deploy your pod over `node 2`

Now if you set a `PDB` with a `minAvailable: 50%`, that `drain` command would fail as it would violates the rule.

The pods is killed and **then** kubelet tries to schedule it somewhere.

PDB allows you to prevent downtime by budgeting pods before evicting them.

**Let's imagine a bad scenario without PDB**

You perform `node 1` update and `node 2` cannot host the evicted pod :

- pod is killed on `node 1`
- kubelet cannot schedule pod anywhere
- autoscaling provisions a third node
- pod is scheduled on that new node

During that whole time your evicted pod was not running anywhere and your application was down.

Comment: When I am using AKS , does it provide the option to add nodes automatically to respect PDB rule which I want  i.e  minUnavailable: 0

Comment: If you've enabled `autoscaling` then yes definitely. You'll find more info here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler#about-the-cluster-autoscaler

Comment: If i have hpa enabled and my minReplica: 5 and maxReplica:15. And if i mention minUnavailable: 5% . Would it be 5% of minReplica or maxReplica?

Comment: That would be 5% of the minReplica. If my answer helped you please consider accepting it :)