# Effect of pod disruption budget on a single replica deployment

Tags: kubernetes

We have a deployment with a single replica.
I have also set a pod disruption budget with minimumAvailability = 1

```yaml
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-selector
```

I have seen behaviour where clusterAutoscaler doesn't wait for the minimumAvailability to be healthy, and kills the pod.

My question is, does having a pod disruption budget works with replica number = 1 & minimum availability = 1?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301551/why-do-we-need-poddisruptionbudget-on-aks/72301917#72301917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix up `PDB` and `maxUnavailable` or `MaxSurge` : there are not the same..

- `PDB` prevents you from scaling down your app against volontary disruptions only, like cluster upgrades where you drain a node for exemple
- `minAvailable` define how many pods should remain up on rollout.
- `maxSurge` define how many pods should be added on rollout

[Why do we need PodDisruptionBudget on AKS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301551/why-do-we-need-poddisruptionbudget-on-aks/72301917#72301917)

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment